# Testing Global Vue.prototype.$http method in Jest which uses axios in Vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, jestjs, axios, jest-mock-axios

I have a global prototype defined in my Vue project in main.js as follows

```
//main.js

import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from 'vue';

Vue.prototype.$http=axios.create({
   baseURL: 'https://example.com/api/' 
});
```

Various vue components directly call `this.$http.get` or `this.$http.post` for performing requests.
How do I test these components in Jest, apparently using mock I can mocks I can do

```
jest.mock('axios')
```

but my project is huge and changing every instance of `this.$http` to axios is not feasible.

How to achieve this using `jest.mock`?

Also how to test if a single component is doing multiple API calls on different endpoints?

Comment: I'd first suggest making your `$http` into a proper [Vue Plugin](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin). That will enable mocking the plugin more easily than the current setup, and the interface will not change for your components that currently expect `this.$http` to exist.

Comment: You will need to mock responses somehow any way. You can try Moxios. It uses existing Axios instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer below code that is giving an idea that how i managed to solve this problem in my project
In My project i have defined global prototype such as-

```js
//main.js
import axios from 'axios'
Vue.prototype.$http = axios  //global prototype
```

And now in my components i can use 'axios' by referring `this.$http`.
Now In my jest file have to test axios get request i.e `this.$http.get('/url')`

```js
// test.spec.js

import axios from 'axios'
    
jest.mock("axios", () => ({
    get: () => Promise.resolve({ data: [{ val: 1 }] })
})); 
    
it('your test name' () => {
    const wrapper = mount('your component name', {
        mocks : {
            $http : axios   
        }   
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://example.com/api/";

Vue.prototype.$http = axios;
```

Comment: You need to add and explanation to this answer explaining how it solves the problem. A code only answer is not sufficient to explain why this is a good solution.